# cakePhP REST configuration

Tags: json, rest, cakephp-2.0

I've read a lot about this but i'm still not sure if my implementation is correct or not as I don't have feedback from the application... I've add the following code to the routes.php

> Router::mapResources('posts');
>       Router::parseExtensions('json');

and the following code on the controller PostsController.php

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
var $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
}

public function view($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    $this->set('post', $this->Post->read());
    $this->set(compact('posts'));
}

public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->set(compact('posts'));
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your post.');
        }
    }
}

public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Post->id = $id;
    if ($this->request->is('get')) {
        $this->request->data = $this->Post->read();
    } else {
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->set(compact('posts'));
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your post has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to update your post.');
            }
        }
}
public function delete($id) {
if ($this->request->is('get')) {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
}
    if ($this->Post->delete($id)) {
        $this->set(compact('posts'));
        $this->Session->setFlash('The post with id: ' . $id . ' has been deleted.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
}
```

}

Is this enough? my goal is to have an android application communicating with an MySQL database trough this webservice. 
Hope you can help me :/

Comment: What do you mean by "is it enough?" ?  Only you can answer that. If it does what you need, then it's enough.  Otherwise, please edit your question to be more specific. Post a sample URL and what output or error you got back.  (also, make sure your `debug>0`.)

Comment: the thing is i don´t how to put the code on that controller ready to receive and send requests to an android application. i could find any info about that

Comment: Forget the android app for now. Just type in the URL manually and see if you get the correct JSON response.  You can also use "REST Client" browser plugins to do testing. On Firefox I use HTTPFox to see the response/headers that are returned.

Comment: type as the url localhost:3030/cake_2_1/posts.get ?

Comment: `/posts.json` . BTW, typed-in URLs are always 'GET'. If you want to test PUT/DELETE/etc, either use a plugin like I mentioned.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function object() on a non-object in C:\www\cake_2_1\app\View\Posts\json\index.ctp on line 5

this appears along with other stuff but the file that its refering to its empty.. any ideas?

Comment: @Costa now the file is really empty :P and what is doing is asking me to download posts.json, i've used the pluggins that you told me and the body was also empty :/ don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Costa i was able to get the REST working (i think XD ) i used one pluggin as he suggested to test it but i was only able to receive a correct answer from http://localhost:3030/cake_2_1/posts/index.json
in the coockbook they have POST /recipes.format RecipesController::add() to add something but how does that translates into an url here? `echo json_encode($message);` is what i have in the View\Posts\json\add.ctp and

`if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $message = 'Saved';
        } else {
            $message = 'Error';
        }
        $this->set(compact("message"));`

is what i have in the controller add function. Almost done just need a little more help :)

Comment: The URL for a POST is the same as for a GET. The difference is the HTTP METHOD used is `POST` instead of `GET`.  You can't test POST via URL alone. You have to actually post a form to the `/posts.json` URL or use a REST client browser addon to create a POST request to `/posts.json` . REST is pretty hard to test this way. Personally, I don't use `mapresources()` and I make everything go through GETs so I can test via bookmarked URLs in my browser.  This is "anti-REST", but it makes it much easier for me to test, and in the end, it all works anyway.

Comment: so what do you use ? how can you test the methods add() and edit(id) ? 
i've add this to the routes.php
`Router::connect( 
    "/:controller/title/body/:id", 
    array("action" => "edit", "[method]" => "PUT"), 
 array("title" => "[a-z]+"),
 array("body" => "[a-z]+"),
    array("id" => "[0-9]+") 
 );`
but it isnt working...

Comment: I test add/edit by posting a form to a url (one controller/action creates the form which is POSTed to another controller/action).  I don't use any routes, it'll just confuse you and create problems.